# RichTextBox vertical auto scrolling text

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I need to build a digital signage application, which will display announcments. Becuase the text shoud have the ability to by designed be the user, I thought about a rich text box control, and the text will be automatically scrolled vertically (like "news" text box).
Any ideas?

Comment: code so far? you could send WM_SCROLL messages periodically to the rich text box. what should happen when scrolling hits the bottom? better control might be possible with a HTML page (which could handle the scrolling from within, JavaScript), and be shown in your VB.NET program using a WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm currently writing this for you while I wait for my train So I haven't tested this but something like this should do the trick.
**NOTE**
If you get the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` ***error***, 
Don't set it to `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` except for debugging purposes.

Although you wont notice anything at the start, having `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`can and will cause problems later on down the track.

With all that said, Here is the code.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0 ''Change to a RichTextBox if you want.
    ''Starting the background worker.
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    ''BACKGROUND WORKER''
    For i = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = i
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)''changing the sleep time will make the textbox scroll to the right faster or slower.
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ''Once completed, The background worker will start again.
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    ''This should stop the program from crashing when closing if the background worker is still running
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
End Sub
End Class
```

**NOTE**
 You will need to use a background worker or else your program will become unresponsive until the `Loop` is complete.

 Once again if you get the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` error, Have a look on Google and search to get get around this problem, However if you are happy to leave it as `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` than that's up to you.
 Let me know how you go, I haven't tested this, however since no one has replied to you in 10 hours, I figured I'd give it a try even without a compiler to test it.

Comment: Hi, i will try this and let you know ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, If you happen to get that error i was talking about, but happy to live with it until you iron out all your code, here is the fix `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` add it to the formload sub

Comment: Why didn't you just make it thread-safe from the beginning? :)

Comment: hahah! yeah you are right, however i don't have a compiler for Vb.net on my crappy netbook, so i didn't want to make an errors that i could at least help lol. so with that being said, when i grow up i want to be a walking compiler hahahahha!

Comment: @Kasper555 how did you go?